# When i change a variable from the code while its running, it changes but immediately goes back to the original value

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

im trying to change the variable "moveSpeed" but when i play it changes by plus 10 (in this case it would be 20 after adding 10) after 10 seconds as it should, but only changes for a second then goes back to 10 again and the process repeats every 10 seconds. i want "moveSpeed" to go like this every 10 seconds, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50. but it wont do that.

[image: here's the code:]

Comment: Please don't paste in a  image of your code, instead paste it in as text, formatted as `code` (look up formatting in the [help])

Answer (score 1):

```
if (transform.position.x > deadzone)
```

The above condition will always run because your dead zone is -45. So your game object is being destroyed and its movement speed resets to 0 every time it moves to the right. I think you meant to do this:

```
if (transform.position.x < deadzone)
```

Comment: thank you but the dead zone thing didn't work my pipes just immediately delete themselves when they are spawned i will keep this in mind though thanks!